# Android TestView extends View

Tags: android

I need a good tutorial on how to do a View Class with OnTouch that also uses Threads any idea where i can see this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In german and without threads but it should give you an idea how it works

http://www.milestone-blog.de/android-development/einfaches-zeichnen-canvas/